# Standard Graded Algebra over a field

Tags: algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

My question is What is standard graded Algebra over a field $K$?

I know this question is already posted here [Standard graded algebra](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133484/standard-graded-algebra)
, But still I'm repeating because the concept is not clear to me.

What I know a graded ring $R$ with gradation ${\{R_n\}}$, where $R_n$ is additive subgroup satisfies

$1.$ $R=\oplus$$R_n$

$2.$ $R_mR_n \subseteq R_{m+n}, \forall m,n\ge0$

and similarly we can define graded $R$ module $M$ with gradation ${\{M_n\}}$ satisfying

$1.$ $M=\oplus M_n$

$2.$ $R_m M_n \subseteq M_{m+n}, \forall m,n \ge0$

But the definition of standard graded algebra $R$ over a field $K$ is according to the article http://www.dima.unige.it/~conca/Articoli%20Conca%20PDF/PDF%20da%20rivista/(2014)%20Conca%20(LNM%20Levico)%20Koszul%20Algebras%20and%20Their%20Syzygies.pdf

is $R=\oplus R_i$ such that $R_0 =K$, the vector space $R_1$ has finite dimension and $R_iR_j=R_{i+j}, \forall i,j \ge 0$

Can anyone please explain this definition in a simpler way?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: That article defines them to be quotients of the polynomial ring $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ by a homogeneous ideal. Does that clarify the concept?

Comment: You mean to say that $R$ is quotient of the polynomial ring $K[x_1 , x_2 , ...,x_n]$ which means that $R$ is finitely generated $K$- Algebra. But my $R$ is just a $K$- algebra. @Joppy

Comment: The definitions are equivalent though, the requirement that $R_1$ has finite dimension over $K$, together with $R_i R_j = R_{i + j}$ means that such an $R$ may always be written as a quotient of $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n]$ where $n = \dim_K R_1$.

Comment: @Joppy So, this article is defining Standard graded Algebra in this way? Like this is not exactly same as Graded Module, But satisfies the properties?

Comment: But then how $R_i$ forms a vector space over $K$?

Comment: How can you say that $R$ may be always written as the quotient of $K[x_1, ..., X_n]$ from the condition $R_iR_j=R_{i+j}$? @Joppy

Comment: Fix a $K$-basis $r_1, \ldots, r_n$ of $R_1$. There is a map of $K$-algebras $K[x_1, \ldots, x_n] \to R$ taking each $x_i$ to $r_i$, and this map is surjective because of the condition $R_i R_j = R_{i + j}$.

Comment: I think the definition of a standard algebra is rather standard, and it is not necessary to have a new question on this subject.